# How to trigger "share via" menu popup as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I build android app with as3.
I need to create a button which will trigger the native share via menu, so i will be able to let the user share the link to my game.

Comment: You need an AIR Native Extension (ANE) to do this. It is possible with just AS3

Comment: Woops. Just realized I made a glaring typo in my comment. It is **not** possible with just AS3

Comment: thank you. do you know any ane that do it maybe? i couldnet find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself, but apparently this might do the job:

https://github.com/mr-archano/Android-AIR-Extensions